# Nested tables with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, nested, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get a thymeleaf page to show something like following on page:

```
Question 1:
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
etc...
```

The amount of answers or questions in page is not known. But it can be calculated from a database if needed.

I'm passing two separate list objects with model.addAttribute. One is called answer and one is called survey. I know both of them work, I can print list of questions or list of answers, but not both at the same time, in this format.

I currently have this code in my HTML page

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <tr th:each="survey : ${survey}">
        <td th:text="${survey.name}">

            <table class="second table">
                <tr th:each="answer : ${answer}">
                    <td th:text="${answer.name}"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

How do I go about nesting the loop so I can present them in the page as shown in beginning?

To be more clear: question = survey.name and answer = answer.name

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Your code seems right, do you have any error or just something doesn't appear on a website?

Comment: The first one appeared on page, second one didnt, but i now got it figured out. no idea why this version didnt work tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone wonders here, you can use nested lists like this:

```
               <table>
                <span th:each="survey : ${survey}">
                    <h1 th:text="${survey.name}"></h1>
                    <td>
                        <tr th:each="answer: ${answer}">
                            <p th:text="${answer.name}"></p>
                        </tr>
                    </td>
                </span>
              </table>
```